# How to use excel 2010 functions to caculate the sum of distinct unique values?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

How to use excel 2010 functions to caculate the sum of distinct unique values?

1. remove the duplicate values
2. sum of distinct unique values
   but I don't need to know who are the distinct unique values, I just need the sum

ex:
A1  1
A2  2
A3  2
A4  3
A5  3
A6  3
A7  4
A8  4
A9  4
A10 4

sum = 1+2+3+4 = 10

I know it may involve excel functions such as SUM, IF, FREQUENCY, MATCH, ROW, etc. But I don't know how to put them together and whatever I try there will be errors. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use "Remove Duplicates" option from Data tab. Select the column 'A' > go to Data tab > click on "Remove Duplicates". This will remove all the duplicated values in the column.

Now, use 'Summation' formula to sum the rest of the cell values in the 'A' column

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how about the solutions using functions. I have hundreds of these data, cannot be processed manually in this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`=SUM(IF(MATCH(U1:U5,U1:U5)+X=ROW(U1:U5),U1:U5,0))`

Replace `U1:U5` with your selected range. Make sure you press Ctrl+Shift+Enter so that it's classed as an array Formula. Also, where it says `+x` replace X with the row# above the start range. In my example it would have been 0.

I played around with the Formula, but hopefully it will work.

It checks if the row of the cell is the first Match, if so it will add it, otherwise it ignores it. As Match doesn't return the actual row, but the row index within that range, you will have to modify X to get the correct row number.